# How to hide sidebar upon user logout and show sidebar when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using the Dashgum bootstrap template which I got from Gridgum for a task that I am assigned to which is to show the side navbar when the user is logged in (even when they close said site) and hide the side navbar like it doesn't exist when the user logs out.

The side navbar is shown in default but I would like to set the default to "hidden". How do I initially hide the side navbar?

I am still new to bootstrap so I am not used to it yet. Asked this on SO as a last resort.

HTML Code for Side navbar

```
<aside>
          <div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse ">
              <!-- sidebar menu start-->
              <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">

                  <p class="centered"><a href="profile.html"><img src="assets/img/ui-sam.jpg" class="img-circle" width="60"></a></p>
                  <h5 class="centered">Marcel Newman</h5>

                  <li class="mt">
                      <a href="index.html">
                          <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                          <span>Dashboard</span>
                      </a>
                  </li>
</ul>
          </div>
      </aside>
```

JS Code for sidebar collapse

```
//    sidebar toggle

    $(function() {
        function responsiveView() {
            var wSize = $(window).width();
            if (wSize <= 768) {
                $('#container').addClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            }

            if (wSize > 768) {
                $('#container').removeClass('sidebar-close');
                $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            }
        }
        $(window).on('load', responsiveView);
        $(window).on('resize', responsiveView);
    });

    $('.fa-bars').click(function () {
        if ($('#sidebar > ul').is(":visible") === true) {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '0px'
            });
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '-210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
            $("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
        } else {
            $('#main-content').css({
                'margin-left': '210px'
            });
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'margin-left': '0'
            });
            $("#container").removeClass("sidebar-closed");
        }
    });
```

I tried changing the css and called the jquery command

```
$("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
```

on the html page enclosed with the javascript tag after loading the css first. The navbar is still displayed by default.

**EDIT 1**
- Revised the premise of the problem to provide more information.

- I would like to thank everyone for responding to my question and I tried all the solutions you presented. The output the I got was usually the table and the side navbar overlapping (when the user is logged in) and upon logout, though the side navbar is hidden, the main content does not shift to the left.

**EDIT 2**
- Since the table and the side navbar overlaps, I decided I should hide the navbar by default but so far I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Can't you simply add the class on the HTML directly: "sidebar-closed" and then toggle it on/off after?

Comment: should I add it here? ```<div id="sidebar"  class="nav-collapse">```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your js if you don't have a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('#main-content').css({
                    'margin-left': '0px'
                });
                $('#sidebar').css({
                    'margin-left': '-210px'
                });
                $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
    }
```

If you already have document.ready, just copy this into your document.ready function:

```
$('#main-content').css({
            'margin-left': '0px'
        });
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'margin-left': '-210px'
        });
        $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code and since I already had a document.ready function at the bottom of the index page, I placed it there. The output was that the table and the side navbar overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had it!

If you look at the toggle function they add and remove `sidebar-close` class based on the window size.

You did `$("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");`

Try replacing class `sidebar-closed` with class `sidebar-close` just like:

`$("#container").addClass("sidebar-close");`

---

Comment: Thank you. I tried replacing the said code but the sidebar still shows.

Comment: Hmm, where did you put the code? It is possible your class gets overwritten after page load. Sidebar toggle calls responsiveView on page load or resize.

Comment: I place the code after at the bottom of the code together with the other javascript functions.